# Are the contents in the front page considered as duplicate of the post?

Tags: seo

I asked this same question on stackoverflow, but closed being off topic. Therefore, I am posting it here.

In Wordpress blogs, the front page of the blog will display many posts in whole or excerpts. When the link to the post is clicked, the content will be opened with an other template file(single.php).

Can we say that the content displayed in the front page and the post pages are considered as duplicate? Does it harm SEO in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is "to what point?" we do know for sure that any similar content is considered duplicate content. That is why most SEO plugins offer the possibility to add a 'no index, no follow' to archive pages (categories, tags, search, date archives).
So, back to your question: if you show the whole posts on home page it does harm your SEO.
It is better to only show a small part and even MUCH better to use the excerpt and manually add an excerpt to each post.